# Autofill is not working with android react native

Tags: react-native

```
<TextInput
     autoCompleteType="username"
     importantForAutofill="yes"
      /><TextInput
         autoCompleteType="password"
        importantForAutofill="yes"
      />
```

I've added this code as per guidance in react-native, but in my android app autofill password from google or any not working.Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please, add more explanation and clarify what you want exactly. Also, add some tags for your question.

Comment: try setting your `textContentType` as well

Comment: textContentType is iOS supported only @comphonia

Answer (score 0):

the working solution for both platforms for RN > 0.66 is:

```js
<TextInput
  textContentType="password"
  autoComplete="password"
/>
```

`textContentType` - IOS (https://reactnative.dev/docs/0.66/textinput#textcontenttype-ios)

`autoComplete` - Android (https://reactnative.dev/docs/0.66/textinput#autocomplete-android)